# Error while translating the data-frame column in pandas : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to translate a column of my dataframe.

Using the below code:

```
# Import the library:

import googletrans

from googletrans import Translator

# Create a translator object:

translator = Translator() 

# Use translate method to translate the column. 

df_review['eng_comments'] = df_review['comments'].apply(translator.translate, dest = 'en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))

df_review
```

but I am getting the error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

I have checked everything and there seems no problem with indexing. Screen shot of the dataframe.

[image]

I am a beginner in coding.

Comment: See [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the index of `df_review['eng_comments']` column. Does it have the same index length as the comments column?

Comment: 'df_review['eng_comments']' is a new column i am trying to save the translated data in, even if i use this line of code : 'df_review['comments'].apply(translator.translate, dest = 'en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))' still the error is same.

Comment: when i tried the same code on a subset of the dataframe : df_review[0:5], the code worked. But why its not working for full length of the column ?

Comment: If the issue is still the same then I would suggest instead of using `apply ` function directly, create a separate function for translate process and iterate through the index of `df_review` dataframe, pass the `comments` value to the created function and then return and save the translated value into `eng_comments` columns.

Comment: I think you are right coz, i just did seem research and found out that google API has a limit of 15K characters, so i must translate each row individually. Can you help me to define a function. I'm a beginner in Python.

Comment: I tried this  -  def translate_text(text):
        text = translator.translate(text, dest = 'en').text
        return text
        

df_review['trans_comments'] = df_review['comments'].apply(translate_text)   Still same error

Comment: I would suggest instead of implementing apply method to dataframe column, just create a separate function and iterate few index through that function and check the output. If it's working fine, then let it continue and test the whole column output.

Comment: Yes, i created a separate function and iterate a few index [0:50] and it worked fine, but when i applied it to whole dataframe, again the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have empty rows in the column you're translating. You can just remove the empty rows and try it again.

```
df_review = df_review.loc[df_review['eng_comments'] != '']
```